# error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLLabelElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using typescript and react with TSX files with definitely typed type definitions, I am getting the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLLabelElement>'.
```

When trying to compile a component with the following TSX

```
<label for={this.props.inputId} className="input-label">{this.props.label}</label>
```

I have already solved but adding here for the next person since the solution didn't show up anywhere when searching (Google or StackOverflow)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The solution was to change the `for` attribute to `htmlFor`

```
<label htmlFor={this.props.inputId} className="input-label">{this.props.label}</label>
```

This is a part of the React library itself which apparently handles `for` differently just like it does `class` (it uses `className`) and not an issue with the definitely typed type definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given is mostly correct, but I want to clarify that the use of "htmlFor" and "className" is related to JavaScript, not limited to the React library. If I were to create a similar label in vanilla JavaScript, I might do the following:

```
const myLabel = document.createElement('label');
myLabel.htmlFor = "foo";
myLabel.innerText = "bar";
myLabel.className = "baz";
```

The reason you use "className" and "htmlFor" in the JSX (TSX) is probably precisely for this reason (the JSX is syntatic sugar for just setting the properties in Javascript yourself).